# What does the notation $D^{-}$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

I am working on problems in my complex analysis book (Conway), and I'm not sure what this notation $D^{-}$ means.

[image]

Earlier, $D_{-}$ is defined to be the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : Im z < 0\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, the author means $\bar D$, the closure of the unit disc, i.e. the set $$\bar D = \{ z : |z| \le 1 \}.$$